# Avoiding column alignment in IEEEeqnarray

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align an expression that extends over multiple lines in such a way that certain terms in the expression are aligned with respect to each other. So far I am using the following with IEEEeqnarray:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCll}
    \phi(x, y, z) & = & \frac{V}{2\pi}\left( & \arctan\left[\frac{(x_2-x) (z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\right]\right.\nonumber\\
    && -\> & \arctan\left[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\right]\nonumber\\
    && -\> & \arctan\left[\frac{(x_2-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\nonumber\right]\\
    && +\> & \left.\arctan\left[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\right]\right)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

which results in
[image]

However, there are two things that I would like to improve:

1) I want to avoid aligning the "-" and "+" signs in lines 2-4 with the V/(2pi) in line 1. All the `arctan` functions should be aligned with each other (I have achieved that) and the "-" and "+" signs should have the normal distance from the `arctan` functions. So the signs should be indented relative to V/(2pi), while the `arctan` should remain aligned with each other. How can I do this?

2) The left parenthesis on the first line should be of the correct size to match the size of the right parenthesis. I suspect the problem is that `\left(` comes before `&` in the code for the first line, so the `\right.` at the end of the first line is somehow discarded. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you use one of the  `amsmath` environments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `align` environment from `amsmath`. Alignment inside `\left` and `\right` doesn't work, so, it's better use manual sizes like `\big`, `\Big`,`\bigg`,`\Bigg`, these allow alignment marks `&` and are manually fine tuned (automatic `\left` and `\right` tend to be too large). Also, use `{}-{}` and `{}+{}` for correct spacing around the binary operators `-` and `+`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\phi(x, y, z) = \frac{V}{2\pi}\biggl( 
      &\arctan\biggl[\frac{(x_2-x)(z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\biggr]\nonumber\\
{}-{} &\arctan\biggl[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\biggr]\nonumber\\
{}-{} &\arctan\biggl[\frac{(x_2-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\biggr]\nonumber\\
{}+{} &\arctan\biggl[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\biggr]\biggr)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility with the `fleqn` environment and the `\medmath` command (medium-sized  formulæ, ~ 80 % of  display style), both from `nccmath` (which loads `amsmath`). 
If you absolutely want the formula in normal, display size, you'll have either to align arctan only in the last three equations, or add a fifth line.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{nccmath, mleftright}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{fleqn}\setcounter{equation}{19}
\begin{equation}
\medmath
{\begin{aligned}[b]
    \phi(x, y, z) = \frac{V}{2\pi} \Biggl(\! &\arctan\mleft[\frac{(x_2-x) (z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\mright] \\
    {}-{} &\arctan\mleft[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\mright] \\
   {} - {}&\arctan\mleft[\frac{(x_2-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}} \mright]\\
   {} + {}&{\mleft.\arctan\mleft[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\mright]\mright)}
\end{aligned}}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still set the equation using `IEEEeqnarray` with only 2 columns, positioning the `-` and `+` via a `l`eft over`lap`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rl}
  \phi(x, y, z) = 
    \frac{V}{2\pi}\Biggl( \arctan &\Biggl[\frac{(x_2 - x) (z_2 - z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2 + (x_2 - x)^2 + (z_2 - z)^2}}\Biggr] \nonumber \\
         \mathllap{{}-{}} \arctan &\Biggl[\frac{(x_1 - x) (z_2 - z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2 + (x_1 - x)^2 + (z_2 - z)^2}}\Biggr] \nonumber\\
         \mathllap{{}-{}} \arctan &\Biggl[\frac{(x_2 - x) (z_1 - z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2 + (x_2 - x)^2 + (z_1 - z)^2}}\Biggr] \nonumber\\
         \mathllap{{}+{}} \arctan &\Biggl[\frac{(x_1 - x) (z_1 - z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2 + (x_1 - x)^2 + (z_1 - z)^2}}\Biggr] \Biggr)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Using `{}-{}` and `{}+{}` forces the correct spacing around the binary operator to ensure they present the way they normally would. Also `\Biggl`...`\Biggr` allows for the appropriately-sized delimiters would the need to worry about it spanning over the `IEEEeqnarray` alignments `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that I have a clever way to do this, using IEEEeqnarray environment.

You need to declare this command in preamble:

```
\newcommand{\sizecorr}[1]{\makebox[0cm]{\phantom{$\displaystyle #1$}}} % Used to seize the height of equation
```

It will seize the correct height of you expression, but it will be invisible. Hence, you need to put the largest expression.

The solution would be:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rClll}
     \phi(x, y, z) & = & \frac{V}{2\pi}\left( \sizecorr{\arctan\left[\frac{(x_2-x) (z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\right]}\right. && \arctan\left[\frac{(x_2-x) (z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\right]\nonumber\\
          &&& -&\arctan\left[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_2-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_2-z)^2}}\right]\nonumber\\
          &&& -&\arctan\left[\frac{(x_2-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_2-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\nonumber\right]\\
          &&& + &\left.\arctan\left[\frac{(x_1-x)(z_1-z)}{y\,\sqrt{y^2+(x_1-x)^2+(z_1-z)^2}}\right]\right)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Font: https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf

[image]

Comment: Ok, so that takes care of point 2) in my question. Can you also address point 1)?

Comment: It is simple, you need to add one array to fit the signs. Have a look at my edited answer :)